# SQL error "must use table variable" while inserting cursor output to variable

Tags: sql, cursor

This is my code -

```
Declare @foldername nvarchar(200)
Declare @folderpath varchar(200)

Create table #Folder(subfolder nvarchar(200),depth int null)

insert into #folder(subfolder,depth) EXEC xp_dirtree 'C:\test' 

Declare Filelist CURSOR for select subfolder from #folder
Open Filelist Fetch next from Filelist insert into @foldername

Exec(@foldername)
```

This is the error message I receive

> "must use table variable" while inserting cursor output to variable

When I run this script in sql it gives error for `@foldername`, that you must user table variable.

Why can't I insert cursor fetch result to variable `@foldername`?

Comment: Is this SQL, or command line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Posting code is not enough to help you solve the problem. Please post some description of what you are trying to achieve, and what is currently not working for you.

Comment: `fetch next from FileList into @foldername;`

Comment: @Laurence..oh yes..its so silly..thanks.

Comment: But now when i print(@foldername) it says must declare scalar variable ;-(